# How to create a PIVOT TABLE without summing a column

Tags: sql, pivot-without-aggregate

Here is my query

```
CREATE view pivmehis WITH ENCRYPTION
as 
SELECT APPROVED, [Not Approved] as REJECT, NULL
FROM 
(SELECT MgtApproval
from LeaveRequest) l
PIVOT 
(
Sum (SchedId) --I DON'T WANT TO SUM THIS COLUMN
FOR MgtApproval IN 
([APPROVED], [REJECT], [NULL])) as pvt
```

Original table results:

```
MgtApproval      SchedId
Approved           1
Reject             2
Null               3
Approved           4
Reject             5
Null               6
```

This is the results I would like to view:

```
Approved    Reject        Null
1           2           3         
4           5           6
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT  rn, APPROVED, [Not Approved] as REJECT, NULL
FROM    (
        SELECT  MgtApproval, SchedID, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY mgtapproval ORDER BY SchedID) AS rn
        FROM    LeaveRequest
        ) l
        PIVOT 
        (
        MIN(SchedId)
        FOR     MgtApproval IN 
                ([APPROVED], [Not Approved], [NULL])
        ) as pvt
```

A `PIVOT` still need any aggregation function, but this one is guaranteed to aggregate on at most one column.

Here's the query on sample data which returns exactly what you want:

```
WITH leaveRequest aS
(
SELECT 'APPROVED' AS mgtapproval, 1 AS SchedID
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Reject' AS mgtapproval, 2 AS SchedID
UNION ALL
SELECT 'NULL' AS mgtapproval, 3 AS SchedID
UNION ALL
SELECT 'APPROVED' AS mgtapproval, 4 AS SchedID
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Reject' AS mgtapproval, 5 AS SchedID
UNION ALL
SELECT 'NULL' AS mgtapproval, 6 AS SchedID
)
SELECT  APPROVED, REJECT, [NULL]
FROM    (
        SELECT  MgtApproval, SchedID, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY mgtapproval ORDER BY SchedID) AS rn
        FROM    LeaveRequest
        ) l
        PIVOT 
        (
        MIN(SchedId)
        FOR     MgtApproval IN 
                ([APPROVED], [Reject], [Null])
        ) as pvt
```

**Update:**

Since you mentioned that your column is in fact a `bit`, you should use this syntax:

```
SELECT  [1] AS approved, [0] AS reject, [-1] AS nil
FROM    (
        SELECT  COALESCE(MgtApproval, -1) AS MgtApproval, SchedID, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY mgtapproval ORDER BY SchedID) AS rn
        FROM    LeaveRequest
        ) l
        PIVOT 
        (
        MIN(SchedId)
        FOR     MgtApproval IN 
                ([1], [0], [-1])
        ) as pvt
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your time.  I tried your code and prompt me an error:

Msg 8114, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Error converting data type nvarchar to int.
Msg 473, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The incorrect value "APPROVED" is supplied in the PIVOT operator.

Comment: @Yonita: your `MgtApproval` seems to be an integer, while you comparing it to a `VARCHAR` value ('APPROVED'). I've updated the post with the sample data you provided and it works. Could you please post you exact table definition?

Comment: I have a lookup table that represents the value:
MgtApproval bit
Approved - true or 1
Reject - false 0r 0
Null - default value

Comment: MgtApproval bit (true or false with default null value)
SchedId int (PK)

Comment: Hi Quassnoi +1:  Thank you sO much for your help.  You got me thinking and your code helped me very much so.:

Here's my sol:
SELECT  1 AS Approved, 0 AS Reject, null as NoApprovalNeeded
FROM    (
        SELECT  MgtApproval, SchedID, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY mgtapproval ORDER BY SchedID) AS rn
        FROM    LeaveRequest
        ) l
        PIVOT 
        (
        MIN(SchedId)
        FOR MgtApproval IN ([1], [0])
        ) as pvt

Comment: @Yonita: glad to hear it works, but I think you still need to wrap your column names into square brackets: `SELECT [1] AS Approved, [0] AS Reject`. Otherwise, you'll be selecting the literal `1`'s and `0`'s, not the `SchedID`s

Comment: Got it! :) I noticed my questions viewed 28x but YOU are the ONLY one that put extra effort to solve this for me.  THANK YOU and bless your heart.